# retrieve the Hostname from an Azure VM

Tags: azure, powershell

For monitor reasons I need to retrieve the hostname of each virtual machine.

I used the nice resource "Resource graph" in Azure Dashboard with following query.

```
project VMnaam = name,
location,
resourceGroup,
subscriptionId,
vmsize = properties.hardwareProfile.vmSize,
VMtype = properties.storageProfile.imageReference.offer,
diskSizeInGB = properties.storageProfile.osDisk.diskSizeGB,
OStype = properties.storageProfile.osDisk.osType,
adminUsername = properties.osProfile.adminUsername,
hostname = properties.osProfile.computerName,
type
 | where type == "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines"
```

which gives me a nice overview of every  virtual machine. But something got my attention in the results. 
the hostname (properties.osProfile.computerName) is the same name as the VMname.
Inside the VM I have checked this and controlled that this is indeed correct so I wanted to check what happens if I change the hostname in my VM.

In my linux VM I changed the hostname rebooted the machine and the new hostname is available in the terminal.

Through Azure Resourc Graph however The change is not visible;
If I manually retrieve the computername with powershell with following powershell code:

```
Login-AzAccount -Subscription "mysub"
$vm = get-azvm -ResourceGroupName "myrg"  -Name "myvm"

$vm.OSProfile.ComputerName
```

I also see the first value of my hostname that was initially setup by Azure but not the new hostname that I changed.

Is it not possible to retrieve a changed hostname from Azure? Does it take a while? Is there any other way to retrieve the hostname from Azure?

Comment: Why do you need the "internal" hostname? As I understand it, from a networking perspective, only the "external" (DNS) hostname matters.

Comment: I will have a look at that. That maybe would be a better way to display in the monitoring. Thnx

Comment: It depends on the purpose of the monitoring

Comment: To keep track of every virtual machine inside some report (in my case this would be Azure Dashboard) so it's managable. And the hostname for each VM was a good approach to add to the report to have a lot of specs of each VM for when to debug.
but I followed your advice and added the DNS name inside the dashboard so thats that thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, it is not possible, azure is not aware of the actual hostname in the vm.

Also the fact that vmname and hostname match is just a coincidence (or rather a default from Azure). If you provision a vm through API you have the ability to set hostname when provisioning and it doesn't have to match vm name (although, it usually makes sense if it does).

edit: according to woter324 recent update seem to have fixed this and now Azure is aware of the actual vm hostname (confirmed for windows)

Comment: So its not a good approach to rely on the fact that the computer name is not the hostname. because if the hostname was changed the data is not correct anymore.

Comment: yes, because azure doesnt have access to your vm os. it is not aware of the changes you make to it. and (like i mentioned) vm name == hostname only because its an azure default when creating the vm

Comment: Microsoft seems to have fixed this (for Windows at least). I guess the Azure VM Agent does it. If you rename your computer in the OS, then restart it, under Overview > Properties > Virtual Machine, Computer name will reflect the actual computer name. To get to it with PowerShell, add `-Status` switch to the `Get-AzVM` cmdlet. A recent change, but seems to work on old VMs too, after a reboot.

Comment: In addition, I've noticed the Computer Name property reverts back to the VM's compute object name when the VM is not running. Start it and it will update again. Probably best to create a tag if you have a difference between the compute object name and computer name.

Answer (score 1):

`(az vm list | ConvertFrom-Json).osProfile.computerName`

Comment: But they asked for the _hostname_, not the _computer name_. Is there reason to assume these will be correlated? If so, you should include that in your answer.